# launching an external application

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to launch another application from my app, specifically the splashtop remote streamer app. Here's what I have so far:

```
string packageName = "com.splashtop.remote.FirstActivity";
Intent splash = new Intent();
splash.SetAction(packageName);
StartActivity(splash);
```

And in my Android Manifest:

```
<activity   android:name="com.splashtop.remote.FirstActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">  
     <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="com.splashtop.remote.FirstActivity" />  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
    </intent-filter>   
</activity>
```

And I get this error in the application output and the app forcecloses:

```
Didn't find class "com.splashtop.remote.FirstActivity" on path: /data/app/roughapp.roughapp-1.apk
```

So how exactly do I change the path it is referring to here

```
on path: /data/app/roughapp.roughapp-1.apk
```

Comment: why are you declaring the activity in your Android Manifest? thats telling the Android system "I have written this code, it will be in my package"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution is to use the **PackageManager** and its method `getLaunchIntentForPackage(String packageName);`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29

This method will return a usable intent or null if the Application is not installed or does not have such an intent.

The **PackageManager** can be retrieve from any **Context** via `getPackageManager();`

Good luck.

Comment: So how exactly do I use this? I'm still pretty new at coding in general, even more so with Android. Thanks!

Comment: startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.splashtop.remote")); //Assuming it is the correct package

Comment: Got an error: The name 'getPackageManager' does not exist in the current context. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious

Comment: I did, I've checked it a few times too. Sorry this isn't working right

Comment: Where do you even get this error?-.- I wrote it in compilable code before I answered.

Comment: capital "s" -.- Also ... this code has to exist within the Activity context since only activities can perform the startActivity

Comment: What he means is that startActivity should start with a lowercase s.

Comment: "this code has to exist within the Activity context since only activities can perform the startActivity"

Comment: What exactly does that mean? I know I seem like a complete idiot right now, thanks for helping me though, I really appreciate it

Comment: The class where the code is present has to be a Activity class. Or invoked upon a reference of the type Activity.

Comment: Oh, it is .NET shit... -.- Well I guess every method should start with a capital letter then. StartActivity and GetPackageManager or just .PackageManager (?) etc.. You should have been able to solve this by yourself by this time :p

Comment: still got that error: http://i.imgur.com/AXoYT6j.png sorry I'm having so much trouble .PackageManager also does that

Comment: Well, I don't use .NET and I do not understand why you do it, you don't seem to have much experience in programming so why you choose monodroid instead of the actual Java implementation which everyone else is using and what most tutorials etc should be using is a bit of a mystery. Use the auto-completion from an empty row and try to find the packagemanager ? or google it?

Comment: Yeah I didn't make the best choice there... Thanks for trying though, I hope I can figure it out. Your answer would answer the question in most other situations so I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare that Activity in your own manifest, it will look for it within your own app. To launch an Activity outside your own application, delete what you put in your manifest and use the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.splashtop.remote","FirstActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: alright, sorry I messed up with the manifest thing, I'm pretty new at this.

I did what you said to do and it gave this error :


    'Android.Content.Intent' does not contain a definition for 'ACTION_MAIN' and no extension method 'ACTION_MAIN' accepting a first argument of type 'Android.Content.Intent' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assemble reference?)

Comment: My bad, you shouldn't include that. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: so I think this is where I got the Idea that I was supposed to declare it in my manifest file. It gives me this when I run it now: [mono-rt] android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.splashtop.remote/com.remote.FirstActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: My God I'm bad at this! See my edited answer. Also, can you verify that splashtop has an activity name `FirstActivity`?

Comment: That is why this method should not be used, since it requires you to know the activity name. If the activity is actually exposed to be used from other Apps then yes, sure. But in a general "launch this App" case, no. Also you misspelled splash, it is "spalsh" in your answer.

Comment: The manifest file for splashtop is pretty messed up for some reason, but there is a line in it that says com.splashtop.remote.RemoteAppactivity"com.splashtop.remote.FirstActivity

Sorry if I did something really dumb assuming that meant something

Comment: @Nicklas The only reason I used the method I did is because I assumed the OP had a specific activity from within SplashTop that he wanted to launch. Your method will launch the app using whatever method the Launcher would use. If you want to deep-link to a specific activity, you have to use this. Thanks for catching the spelling error!